# IntelliJ configuration directory

Tags: configuration, intellij-idea

Is there a way to configure the directory where all the configuration files are stored by IntelliJ IDEA (version 8.0.1)?

By default, these files are stored in *%home%*\.IntelliJIdea80... (or .IdeaIC12 etc.), but I want to define another location...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can change this in you `%idea installation directory%\bin\idea.properties`. Edit this in-place or copy the whole file to your `%home%` directory to keep the setting across different versions of idea.

Answer (score 2):

Locations can be changed by editing the following file:

> IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties

Follow the comments in idea.properties file to change the defaults, make sure to un-comment the lines defining these properties:

- idea.config.path
- idea.system.path
- idea.plugins.path
- idea.log.path

Common cases when you may need to change the [default locations of the IDE files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-changing-ide-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage?page=2):

- user profile drive runs out of space
- disk is slow and you want to use faster HDD or SSD for caches
- default user profile points to the UNC path unsupported by the IDE
- home directory is on a network drive user profile directory is not detected correctly
- you want to create a portable installation on a USB stick
- home directory is encrypted and slows down the IDE or causes caches corruption
- caches should be excluded from the home directory
- backup antivirus or search indexer is scanning the home directory affecting IDE
  performance